# JavaScript dateFormat error?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get a field named `BASVURUTARIHI(Date)` from DataSet. But if I only bind it with Eval, it shows `dd/mm/yyyy HH/MM/SS`. I don't want the hours and minutes. So, I am trying to change the dateformat but it gives me the error:

> CS0103: The name 'dateFormat' does not exist in the current context

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# dateFormat(Eval("BASVURUTARIHI"),"dd/mm/yyyy") %>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
```

I don't know a lot about JavaScript. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: It's not JavaScript - this is something called ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BASVURUTARIHI", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")%>'></dx:ASPxLabel>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ASP.NET code, try to have this instead:

```
Text='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("BASVURUTARIHI")).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") %>'>
```

**Edit**: to avoid error when the value is null, change to:

```
Text='<%# (Eval("BASVURUTARIHI") == null) ? "" : ((DateTime)Eval("BASVURUTARIHI")).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") %>'>
```

Comment: Text='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("BASVURUTARIHI")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'> worked! Thank you!!

Comment: what should I do if the date is null?

Comment: @Gece no, you can accept only one. As Waqas answer is better please accept it - he's using the best practice, I just "patched" your existing code with minimal changes. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# date("j/ n/ Y",Eval("BASVURUTARIHI")) %>'>
                        </dx:ASPxLabel>
```